# Size of iPad Simulator is too big in XCodes 4.3.2

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode4.3

Now i am using macbook pro with 13 inches.

Yesterday i upgraded XCodes version to 4.3.2.

In that iPad Simulator is too big and iPad Retina Simulator is also too big.

It's not fix my screen.

iPad Retina Simulator size is take all of my screen and it's can only show iPad's dock.

I can't see overview iPad screen.

I always scroll down and up to test.

When i change Simulator's Window > Scale into 75 %, It's still too big.

50% is too small and can't see anything clearly.

When i develop with XCodes 4.2 , iPad Simulator is fix size and okay to test.

I want iPad simulator size fix my screen.

Is there anyways?

If my question is out of question, so sorry for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because the iPad 3 have a really large resolution (2048x1536). That's more than most computer screens. You *will* need to zoom out to display the entire screen just because of this, or you must get a larger (higher resolution) screen for your computer if you don't want to scale the program.

The reason for this is that the iPad 3 have much tighter pixel density than most other computer screens so each pixel on the iPad is smaller than each pixel on your computer screen.

Comment: I actually don't run the simulator myself, but in your question you said it's possible to scale the window. That's the same thing as resizing the simulator, is it not?

Comment: Yes.Thanks. I just wanna know is there other ways. :)

Comment: You said that at 50% you couldn't see anything clearly. That's because your screen have worse pixel density than the iPad. When you scale the simulator it will have to *remove* pixels, which makes it harder and harder to read since you don't get to see everything the iPad screen would display. I guess that's the reason the simulator is so big - so you can see everything as the iPad would display it! It's therefore impossible to combine `scaling of the simulator` with `making it possible to see details`.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make the simulator start by suppressing the title bar and your dock if it happens to be shown.

Follow these steps, please be responsible and back-up your files before editing anything as I do not take responsibility for things going wrong.

Before you start close any running simulators.

1. In Finder Press `CMD+SHIFT+G` and enter the folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/`; this folder may differ for you depending on your location of the simulator/SDK.
2. Backup the file called `Info.plist`
3. Copy `Info.plist` to your home directory.
4. Double click `Info.plist` in your home directory. You will be presented with the plist editor.
5. Select the first entry called `Information Property List` and click the plus (+) sign immediately to the right.
6. Enter `Application UI Presentation Mode` into the Key field of the new entry, tip: it will auto populate after typing `Application UI`.
7. Enter `4` in the `Value` field, this will then change to `All Suppressed`.
8. Save and close the file.
9. Replace the original plist file with this new one, remember to back the original up first.

Now when you run the simulator it will not show the menu bar when it becomes active. The reason you needed to copy the file to your home directory is because you do not have write permission to it. It also stops you mucking it up and preventing the simulator running while editing the file.

You can apply this trick to any application by finding it's plist file, thus I also change Xcode.app to do this too.

You will need to scale the simulator to 75%, however it will now be almost the full height of the screen with no loss of the iPad window.

Answer (score 0):

Now It's more flexible with Xcode 9- Simulator. You can pick & drag any corner or simulator to resize it and set it according to your requirement.

Look at this snapshot.

[image]

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205865/ios-simulator-screen-size-not-equal-to-window-size